# Update ненулевые поля

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
  UPDATE table
  SET field1= _field1 
    , field2= _field2
    , field3= _field3
  WHERE <condition>;
```

Поля строковые, часть полей могут быть пустыми (не нулл), возможно ли в Update написать так, чтобы обновлялись только непустые поля?

Придумалось через case:

```
  UPDATE table
  SET field1= CASE _field1 WHEN '' THEN (SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE <condition> ELSE _field1 END
    , ...
  WHERE <condition>;
```

Возможно существует какой-то способ попроще?

UPD: с кейсом что-то заклинило, можно ведь написать так:

```
  UPDATE table
  SET field1= CASE _field1 WHEN '' THEN field1 ELSE _field1 END
    , ...
  WHERE <condition>;
```

Но может есть еще проще способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `CASE` выглядит наиболее понятным. Можно ещё совместить `NULLIF` с `COALESCE`:

```sql
UPDATE table
   SET field1 = COALESCE(NULLIF(field1, ''), _field1)
-- ...
```

Но мне этот вариант кажется менее читаемым.

Comment: а по производительности разница будет между case и связкой coalesce + nullif ?

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос вы сможете получить только прогнав бенчмарки на вашей версии Постгреса, ОС, и вашем железе.

Comment: спасибо будем тестить